# Does Apple allow TabBar position on top of view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am working on an application and in this application, there is a requirement of UITabBar on the top position of UIViewController. I need your support to know that, does Apple Guideline allow to set UITabBar position on the top of view?

Comment: you'll have to create a custom component for this. I had to so this in one of my projects.

Comment: What exactly approach you have adopted?

Comment: It violates Apple human interface guidelines.

Comment: I have used a scroll view and then kept adding custom buttons to it as required. Also went through UITabBarViewController class and implemented all the functions they have provided.

Comment: you can use something like Pager https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip

Answer (score 0):

you won't use UITabBar, but you might want to make custom view, or segmented control, or even scroll view.

all depends on your approach

but definitely you can't use UITabBar